# Open File Dialog Goes to wrong directory

Tags: c#, directory

I have a program where I open multiple files and do things with them.  I have button to select the default location and store it as a setting.

```
OpenFileDialog defLoc = new OpenFileDialog()
{
    CheckPathExists = true,
    Title = "Select the default folder"
};

if (defLoc.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultFolder = 
        System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(defLoc.FileName);
    Console.WriteLine("Default folder set: " + Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultFolder);
}
```

Now after this there are 2 other select file buttons. They each have their own OpenFileDialog in their own methods.  For some reason they seem to share a group memory of the last location that was over. Example:

First I set DefaultLocation to `C:\Desktop`

Then I use OpenFile1 to select `C:\Desktop\GenericFolder\GenericFile1.txt`

Now when I use OpenFile2 I want to start back at the location set as default, `C:\Desktop`, but instead end up starting in `C:\Desktop\GenericFolder`.

In my code I do this when I initialize each OpenFileDialog:

```
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultFolder,
            RestoreDirectory = false,
        };
```

This should be putting me at the location I am setting, but for some reason it doesn't.  Instead it just spits me out at the last open location as I demonstrated above.

EDIT:
On the advice of Steve I added `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` right after the `Console.WriteLine();` in the default file picker.

Comment: when you use the debugger.. what is the value of `InitailDirectory` when you step through the code..? also have you looked at MSDN examples on how to use the `OpenFileDialog` ? there are lots of working examples of how to do this online

Comment: did you call save()?

Comment: @Steve Thanks... I can't believe I forgot that.  It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not call `Save()` after setting the path. The next time you start your application the setting got reset.